# Start windows batch from C++ CreateProcess has different behavior

Tags: c++, windows, batch-file, cmd, poco-libraries

Environment: windows 10, VS2013.

I have a C++ app, using Poco framework (Poco 1.7.6) and I need to launch some batch files. It works without problem, but for a particular script, and I can't figure out the reason. 
This particular script is as follows (let's call it `buildMySolution.bat`):

```
set BUILD_DIR=%~dp0
call "C:\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"
msbuild /p:Platform=%~1 /p:Configuration=%~2  %BUILD_DIR%\Mysolution.sln
```

As you can see the batch file simply compiles a VS2013 solution. Needless to say that this simple batch works perfectly well if launched from command line.

The problem is that this batch is in drive D: (in `D:\DevRoot\build\MySolution`) and when launched from my app (in D:\ drive as well), I get a "cannot find the path" on the second line.

I tried several modifications in the batch: like forcing `C:` or `cd /D C:` ... it can go to C: but not further, it refuses to cd to the directory containing vcvarsall.bat (again, I know the path is correct as the very same script executes fine from command line). It has however no problem coming back to initial directory through a `cd /D %BUILD_DIR%`.

To launch the script from my C++ app, I use this:

```
Poco::ProcessHandle handleBuild = Poco::Process::launch(path_to_script, argsBuild);
handleBuild.wait();
```

The Poco `launch` is just a thin wrapper around `CreateProcessA()`, I don't see anything special in their code ([Poco Process.cpp](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/develop/Foundation/src/Process_WIN32.cpp)).

I tried as well to specify the working directory to be the directory containing vcvarsall.bat, but then CreateProcess fails.

Comment: You state `the batch is in drive D:` but your code says `"C:\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"`. - please clarify where the files are and how you've tried `"forcing c:"` etc.

Comment: The batch is called buildMySolution.bat and is in D:\ . Inside the batch I need to invoke vcvarsall.bat whihc resides in C:\ . This does not work when buildMySolution.bat is started from my C++ app, but works well when launched directly in cmd.exe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found a solution: I changed the line (in the batch `buildMySolution.bat`):

```
call "C:\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"
```

to:

```
call C:\PROGRA~2\micros~1.0\vc\vcvarsall.bat
```

Believe it or not: using DOS names and removing quotes makes it work!!!

Bug or feature, I'm not sure...

Comment: You might try launching `cmd /c buildMySolution.bat` instead of launching the batch file directly.  It's possible that running the batch file directly is putting the batch processor in some sort of legacy mode, though if so I don't recall ever hearing about it.

Comment: @Harry: yes I've tried launching cmd.exe /c buildMySolution.bat, but that didn't help. Anyway works now, but still puzzled...

Comment: Hmmm.  Does `cmd /c start cmd /c buildMySolution.bat` still exhibit the unexpected behaviour?  If so, you could try `cmd /c start cmd` to get an interactive shell that hopefully exhibits the same problem, allowing you to experiment.  If you're still curious, that is.

Comment: ... if you don't find anything, I'll see if I can replicate the problem when I get back to work in the new year.  It might be triggered by CREATE_NO_WINDOW or perhaps by using CreateProcessA rather than CreateProcessW, or the combination of both.  Possibly a bug in  Windows 10.

Comment: What build of Windows 10 are you running?

Comment: Windows version: 1607 OS build: 14393.576. But I'd rather learn which function I can invoke to get the DOS name from a filename (because my "buildMySolution.bat" scripts are themselves generated).

Comment: [GetShortPathName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364989(v=vs.85).aspx).